# MongoDB filter aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate-functions

I have a schema for users following as follows

```
const userFollowing = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        profileID: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Profile'
        },
        followingProfiles: [{
            profileID:{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Profile'
            },
            _id: false
        }]
    }
)
```

I am trying to get a the users Following list but i want to add a field containing the whether he is followed back or not

**The intented result**

```
[
{
profileID: "userThatImFollowing",
isFollowed: true
},
{
profileID: "userThatImFollowing",
isFollowed: false
},
]
```

so the aggregation i did so far is

```
 UserFollowing.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                profileID: userProfile._id
            }
            
        },
        {
            $project: {
                followingProfiles:{
                    $slice: ["$followingProfiles", 0, 10]
                },
                _id: 0
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$followingProfiles'
        },{
            $lookup: {
                from: 'userfollowings',
                localField: 'followingProfiles.profileID',
                foreignField: 'profileID',
                as: 'profiles'
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                followingProfiles:1,
                profiles: '$profiles.followingProfiles'
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields:{
                profilesTest:{
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$profiles',
                        as: 'profile',
                        cond : { $eq: ['$$profile.profileID', 'myProfileID']}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec()
```

But profile Tests doesnt give back any value although im sure it should give some value so what am i doing wrong

**EDIT**
Some sample data as requested
Profile collection

```
 [ {
 "_id":"5f03d13de9987e6677650dbe"
 "isPrivate": false,
 "displayPicture": "https://safarni.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/profileImages/defaultimagethumbnail.jpg",
    "displayName": "Shahoda",
    "userName": "GameHunter2"
},
{
 "_id":"5f03d13de9987e6677650dbe"
    "isPrivate": false,
    "displayPicture": "https://safarni.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/profileImages/defaultimagethumbnail.jpg",
    "displayName": "Shahoda",
    "userName": "GameHunter2",
},
{

    "_id": "5f03d151e9987e6677650dc8",
    "isPrivate": false,
    "displayPicture": "https://safarni.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/profileImages/defaultimagethumbnail.jpg",
    "displayName": "Shahoda",
    "userName": "GameHunter",
    
}
```

UserFollowings collection

```
[
{
"profileID":"5f03d151e9987e6677650dc8"
"followingProfiles":[{
   "profileID":"5f03d13de9987e6677650dbe"
},{
   "profileID":"5f03d148e9987e6677650dc3"
}
]

}]
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you provide some sample data as well

Comment: @thammada.ts i wish the sample data i added would be of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it's not working?**

The `profiles` fields immediately after this `$lookup` stage:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'userfollowings',
  localField: 'followingProfiles.profileID',
  foreignField: 'profileID',
  as: 'profiles'
}
```

is an array. And in the `$project` stage that follows:

```
$project: {
  followingProfiles:1,
  profiles: '$profiles.followingProfiles'
}
```

you are trying to access `followingProfiles` from `$profiles` like it's an object(when it's not). The result of this project stage would make `profiles` an array of array, something like this:

```
{
  "followingProfiles": {
    "profileID": "5f03d13de9987e6677651dbc"
  },
  "profiles": [
    // Notice the nested array here
    [
      {
        "profileID": "5f03d13de9987e6687650dbe"
      },
      {
        "profileID": "5f03d13de9987e6677650dbe"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The `$addFields` stage that follows:

```
$addFields:{
  profilesTest:{
      $filter: {
          input: '$profiles',
          as: 'profile',
          cond : { $eq: ['$$profile.profileID', 'myProfileID']}
      }
  }
}
```

is trying to filter the `profiles` array, thinking it's an array of objects, whereas, it's an array of array of objects. This is why the `profilesTest` result is always an empty array.

**The Fix:**

An easy fix would be to avoid having `profiles` as an array of array. You can do this by adding a `$set` stage just after the `$lookup` to extract the inner array and keep it at the top level, something like this:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      profileID: userProfile._id,
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      followingProfiles: {
        $slice: [ "$followingProfiles", 0, 10]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$followingProfiles"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "followingProfiles.profileID",
      foreignField: "profileID",
      as: "profiles"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      profiles: {
        // Extract the inner array and keep it at the top level
        $arrayElemAt: [ "$profiles", 0]
      }, 
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      followingProfiles: 1,
      profiles: "$profiles.followingProfiles"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      profilesTest: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$profiles",
          as: "profile",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$profile.profileID", userProfile._id ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // The additional $project stage is to reformat the document to give the intended result 
  {
    $project: {
      profileID: "$followingProfiles.profileID",
      isFollowed: {
        $cond: [
          { $arrayElemAt: [ "$profilesTest", 0] },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can simplify the aggregation by adding a nested pipeline in the `$lookup` stage, something like this:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      profileID: userProfile._id
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      followingProfiles: {
        $slice: ["$followingProfiles", 0, 10]
      },
      _id: 0
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$followingProfiles"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { profileID: "$followingProfiles.profileID" },
      as: "profileDetails",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ "$profileID", "$$profileID" ]
            },
            // Check for a follow back
            "followingProfiles.profileID": userProfile._id,
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      profileID: "$followingProfiles.profileID",
      isFollowed: {
        $cond: [
          { $arrayElemAt: [ "$profileDetails", 0 ] },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Notice how you can easily check for a follow-back within the nested pipeline. More details about using the `$lookup` stage with a pipeline [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Comment: Thank You very much for your help i didn't notice the nested array part so thanks for clarification i just do not understand the part  `{$eq: [$profileID, $$profileID]}` what does $profileID and $$profileID refer to

Comment: `$profileID` refers to the value of `profileID` in the current document the pipeline is processing while `$$profileID` refers to the value of a variable declared in the `$lookup.let` option. You can use any other valid variable name if you like, the double $ sign indicates that you’re trying to access the variable. More details on the the `$lookup.let` option [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-join-let).

Comment: your help is really appreciated one last question does  `'followingProfiles.profileID': userProfile._id` makes the profileDetails contain a followingProfiles containing only the profile of userProfile right ? or i got the wrong idea cause at first i thought it did that but when i tried making a user follow more than one profile it also returned them in profileDetails.followingProfiles or it returns the whole array if one of the objects contaib userProfile._id

Comment: _does `'followingProfiles.profileID': userProfile._id` makes the profileDetails contain a followingProfiles containing only the profile of userProfile_ -> **NO**. The query filter: `'followingProfiles.profileID': userProfile._id` is there to ensure that the user the aggregation pipeline is currently processing includes `userProfile._id` as a `profileID` in of its subdocuments in the `followingProfiles` array. If there is a match, the output for `followingProfiles` is the whole array of `profileID`s as listed in the original document(pre-match).